# Configure PhpStorm to import watchers automatically at project start

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, file-watcher

I have setup some file watchers (like: jshint, uglifyjs, sass, ...) in PhpStorm.

Already I've exported them into a `xml` file extension for later use in my upcoming projects.

I could manually import this file at the beginning of every project that I will start; but is there any option to configure PhpStorm to automatically import watchers at every project creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no options for this a.t.m. Please follow corresponding feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8414